# add_argument for user agent cuts off at first space

Tags: ruby, selenium, heroku, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

### Meta

OS: macOS High Sierra

Selenium Version: 3.9.0

Browser: Chrome

Browser Version: 64.0.3282.167 (Official Build) (64-bit)

### Problem

I'm using Ruby and the Selenium WebDriver to view a webpage using headless Chrome.

I need to change the user agent for my project. On my local computer, I can easily do this via the **add_argument** method in Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options:

```
options = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.167 Safari/537.36')
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for(:chrome, options: options)
puts driver.execute_script('return navigator.userAgent')
```

This (correctly) returns:

> Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.167 Safari/537.36

However, when I push this code to my Heroku app and run the same code*, suddenly here's what gets returned:

> Mozilla/5.0

I have spent a ton of time trying all kinds of fixes. Pretty early on I realized this was probably some kind of escaping issue, so I looked up how to escape spaces and (I think) have tried absolutely everything: backslashes, double-backslashes, quotes, double-quotes, etc. None of it has worked.

I even tried:

```
options.add_argument('--user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.167 Safari/537.36"')
```

Which only returned:

> "Mozilla/5.0

As far as I can tell, absolutely any user agent I pass as an option will get cut off at the first space.

Am I missing something obvious here?

Thank you!

**The only change I make to the code running on Heroku is that I have to slightly update the first line of code above to point the Heroku app to the Chrome binary:*

```
options = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new(binary: ENV['GOOGLE_CHROME_SHIM'])
```

Comment: If you have found out the answer yourself, instead of adding the answer as an update within the question, post it as an answer for the future readers.

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't figured out the answer yet. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wish I could take credit for this, but I actually got the answer in a Chromedriver forum: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=2276#c7.

In short, [the Heroku buildpack](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-google-chrome/blob/master/bin/compile#L142) I've been using had a bug that prevented arguments with spaces from being parsed correctly.

This line...

```
exec \$HOME/.apt/opt/google/$BIN --headless --no-sandbox --disable-gpu --remote-debugging-port=9222 \$@
```

...should have looked like this:

```
exec \$HOME/.apt/opt/google/$BIN --headless --no-sandbox --disable-gpu --remote-debugging-port=9222 "\$@"
```

I've since filed [a PR](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-google-chrome/pull/40) that will fix the issue.

In the meantime, anyone can use [my forked version](https://github.com/jaypinho/heroku-buildpack-google-chrome) of the buildpack, which I've verified parses the user agent correctly.