# Robot Framework calling add_argument with spaces

Tags: selenium-webdriver, robotframework, user-agent

In order to set a custom user-agent of browser used by robot framework, I've found every where that you can set that like that :

```
    ${options}=                         Evaluate
    ...                                 sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].ChromeOptions()
    ...                                 sys, selenium.webdriver
    Call Method                         ${options}
    ...                                 add_argument                            --user-agent\=User agent with spaces

    Create WebDriver                    Chrome                                  chrome_options=${options}

    Go To                               https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-is-my-user-agent
```

But the value of the add_argument `User agent with spaces` is not escaped and it adds unwanted wrong tabs in the browser :
[image]

The user agent detected by whatismybrowser.com is `User`.

My question is pretty simple, how do I pass argument values that have spaces ?

I've tried :

- `User agent with spaces`
- `User\ agent\ with\ spaces`
- `User\\ agent\\ with\\ spaces`
- `User${SPACE}agent${SPACE}with${SPACE}spaces`
- `User\${SPACE}agent\${SPACE}with\${SPACE}spaces`
- `"User agent with spaces"`
- `'User agent with spaces'`

None of these works...

Comment: you can try with triple quotes '''User agent with spaces'''

Answer (score 3):

I've found the root cause of my problem.

While searching deeper about my problem, I've found that question that is exactly the problem I had too : [add_argument for user agent cuts off at first space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48859726/add-argument-for-user-agent-cuts-off-at-first-space)

I'm using a robot-framework docker image here : https://github.com/ppodgorsek/docker-robot-framework

The binary launcher `bin/chromium-browser.sh` contains the bash positional argument operator unquoted :

```sh
#!/bin/sh

exec /usr/lib/chromium/chrome-original --disable-gpu --no-sandbox $@
```

Replacing that with a quoted positional argument operator solve the problem and I can set a custom user-agent of the controlled browser.

```sh
#!/bin/sh

exec /usr/lib/chromium/chrome-original --disable-gpu --no-sandbox "$@"
```